# Finding residue through series method

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration

I was trying to find the residue of the function.

$$\frac{1}{e^{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}}$$

Any clue/help would be appreciated.

The answer is $-1/e.$

Thanks

Comment: Isn't it $e^{-e^{1/z}}$ ?

Comment: Sorry for the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You may write 
$$e^{-e^{1/z}} = e^{-1-\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{2!z^2} +...} =  e^{-1} e^{-1/z} e^{-1/2z^2} ... = e^{-1} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{2!z^2} -...\right) \left(1-\frac{1}{2z^2}+\frac{1}{2! (2z^2)^2} ...\right) ...$$
You find only one term contributing to the residue.

Comment: Not getting it after this.I had reached till here before.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$
1-e^{1/z}=-\frac1z+O\!\left(\frac1{z^2}\right)
$$
we have
$$
e^{1-e^{1/z}}=1-\frac1z+O\!\left(\frac1{z^2}\right)
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
e^{-e^{1/z}}
&=e^{-1}\cdot e^{1-e^{1/z}}\\
&=e^{-1}\left(1\color{#C00000}{-\frac1z}+O\!\left(\frac1{z^2}\right)\right)
\end{align}
$$
Thus, we get the residue to be $-e^{-1}$.